# Issue with iOS team provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5

We have few provision profiles in our Apple account.Recently I met with an issue regarding iOSTeam provisioning profiles.I saw more iOSTeam provisioning profiles in our account and same profiles are reflecting in Xcode while selecting profile.My issue is even though I have deleted all the iOSTeam provisioning profiles in Apple account when I refreshed all are reverting back into the account.Same thing happening in Xcode also.I don't know how to delete them permanently.I attached few screens here related to that issue.If you know why this happening please guide me to resolve this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this "Iphone Configuration Utility" from Apple.

Comment: iPhone Configuration Utility is pulled away by Apple, but you can still use it to do achieve what you want [Download Here](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/iPhone-Configuration-Utility.shtml)